# C++ Game Programming Resources

Tags: c++, 3d

Where can i get some advanced game programming resources for c++?

Comment: @iKlsR please don't use URL shorteners, we like to be able to know what we're being linked to. Especially not for lmgtfy: it's actually blocked from being linked to, and for a reason.

Comment: im sorry. that guy really ticked me off. if someone has nothing constructive or helpful to say. just continue browsing.

Comment: I'm sorry, this question/your LMGTFY comment/your attitude really ticked me off. If you don't have an actual question to ask or anything constructive to say, please don't post a question. Voting to close.

Comment: no comment. im new here so i'll try to abide by the rules.

Comment: @iKlsR: This isn't your personal resource for people to do your work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At http://gamedev.stackexchange.com ?
More specifically, this [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5465/starting-programming-in-3d-with-c) and lots of others tagged with [c++](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)

Comment: im afraid thats a little too advanced for me, i recently moved away from command prompt and some basic gui. I want to start smaller.

Comment: I pointed out to a specific question. I think you go only that much when you want 3d in C++. If you like to start small, try with pygame and python.

Comment: i am as a matter of fact. i just want to expand my skills to accommodate c++.

Comment: @iKlsR: I think you had asked another question for Python. If you want to learn C++, just develop simple games with any resource you stumble upon. Nothing can replace practice.

Answer (score 1):

Start with writing some simple 2D games, e.g. Snake, TicTacToe, etc. Write these using any GUI builder you're already familiar with.

Then try to rewrite these games using a serious graphic engine, e.g. SDL, OpenGL, or DirectX.

Then try to write a more complex 2D games, e.g. side-scroller. Write these games with the graphic engine of your choice.

Then add some simple 3D effect to your 2D game, e.g. [parallax scrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling).

Then rewrite this effect with true 3D, use 3D models/sprites, 3D environment, etc, while maintaining a 2D look and feel.

Then add some simple 3D look and feel, e.g. allowing characters to move in the Z-direction (to/from the camera), doing camera rotation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you just got out of the command prompt and simple GUI, you'll probably want to start simple.
I'd very much recommend OpenGL as your API of choice.  Since you've done some simple GUI programming, you'd know what an API is.

OpenGL has the following advantages (compared to SDL and DirectX previously mentioned):

-Its hardware accelerated (SDL is not as far as I know)
-Its 3D (SDL is 2D)
-Its cross-platform (DirectX is Windows only)

By far the best place to start with OpenGL is the Nehe tutorials.

http://nehe.gamedev.net/

Game programming becomes evident once you become a bit more familiar with the API.

Also, I'd heartily recommend GLUT (OpenGL Utilities Toolkit).  It simplifies window creation and user input handling, among other things.  Its great for learning OpenGL.  It also happens to be cross platform.

Here's freeglut, a free GLUT implementation:

http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/

OpenGL is also a relatively simple and easy API to learn.  You'll be going into 3D in no time.

Answer (score 0):

What libraries are you using? You can try [GP wiki](http://gpwiki.org/index.php/Game_Programming_Wiki). It can be a bit hit and miss depending on what you want to use.

Comment: im using the directx sdk if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

By "resources," do you mean tools? Libraries?  Tutorials?  I have a bunch of [useful game developer links](http://www.ariasamp.net/index.php/brain-dump) in the sidebar of my own site.  I also think "[Mathematics for Game Developers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584500379)" was very helpful.  It has a second edition as well.

Comment: more tutorials than libraries. i try to use libraries as little as possible when coding.

Comment: Ah! Then do take a look at the links on my own site. :)